# Combine string_split column results in table SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, split

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for updating a table in a batch. I want to take parameters in as a `nvarchar` and call `string_split` on them.

```
@ParamList1 NVARCHAR(max) = '1,2,3,4,5'
@ParamList2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'a,b,c,d,e'
```

I want to get a temporary table like

```
Param1  Param2
1       a
2       b
3       c
...
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `string_split()` does not guarantee ordering or provide a position argument (Microsoft are you listening?).

So, the safest method is a recursive CTE (or perhaps another approach using XML):

```
with cte as (
      select convert(nvarchar(max), NULL) as x1, convert(nvarchar(max), NULL) as x2, @paramlist1 as rest1, @paramlist2 as rest2, 1 as lev
      union all
      select convert(nvarchar(max), left(rest1, charindex(',', rest1 + ',') - 1)),
             convert(nvarchar(max), left(rest2, charindex(',', rest2 + ',') - 1)),
             stuff(rest1, 1, charindex(',', rest1 + ','), ''),
             stuff(rest2, 1, charindex(',', rest2 + ','), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest1 <> '' and rest2 <> ''
     )
select *
from cte
where x1 is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e09d604a8498892787d821c1f38f07ed) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow that's great, thanks. Never heard of a correlated subquery before.

Comment: What is the reason for "lev < 10"?

Comment: @Benny  . . . (1) That is a recursive CTE.  I can't believe my fingers typed something else.  (2) The comparison on `lev` is just something I always put in when testing recursive CTEs.  I removed it.

Comment: Since `STRING_SPLIT()` needs v2016+ there is `OPENJSON` as a type-safe and position-safe string splitter. You might [read this (UPDATE sections)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275075/5089204)

Answer (score 0):

You've got an answer already, which is working fine, but this should be faster and easier:

You did not specify your SQL-Server's version, but - talking about `STRING_SPLIT()` - I assume it's at least v2016. If this is correct, you can use OPENJSON. Your list of numbers needs nothing more than brackets to be a JSON-array (`[1,2,3]`), while an array of words/letters can be transformed with some easy string operations (`["a","b","c"]`).

Following the docs, OPENJSON returns the elements position in `[key]`, while the element itself is returned in `[value]`. You can simply JOIN these sets:

```
DECLARE @ParamList1 NVARCHAR(max) = '1,2,3,4,5';
DECLARE @ParamList2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'a,b,c,d,e';

SELECT p1.[key] AS FragmentNr
      ,p1.[value] AS P1
      ,p2.[value] AS P2
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[',@ParamList1 + ']')) p1
INNER JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(@ParamList2,',','","'),'"]')) p2 ON p1.[key]=p2.[key] ;
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275075/5089204) you will find some details (UPDATE section 1 and 2).